# How to listen to Vue Slots' changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wonder how to listen to the slot's changes. Like I have a container component, I can adjust the container or something when I listen to the changes.

I have tried to use watch to listen `this.$slots` in deep, but that actually doesn't work as I expected. Also, Copilot inspired me by using mutation observer, I think that will work, but it's a little too heavy for me.

And here is what I have tested. I am building a drawer component, which can be expanded and show all inner elements or be closed by changing the drawer's height to 0px. So in this scene, it's kind of essential to know if the slot's content is changed by others instead of the drawer itself. For example, if the slot's height changes to 200px, I would not be noticed and cause visual issues because the drawer component still thinks the slot should be 100px.

The drawer component is simple, so I give what I tried instead:

```
    '$slots': {
      handler() {
        console.log(this.$slots, 'slots')
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
```

I add these codes in the watch, and because of immediate logs will appear when the page is inited. But never when the slot's content changed:

```
<test-drawer :expand="openNow">
  <a-test-component v-if="!timeout"></a-test-component>
</test-drawer>
```

I put a test component inside and will hide it after timeout:

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.timeout = true
  }, 5000)
}
```

And I keep the drawer open. When the timeout is true, I can see the inner component disappears, but no logs come out. This test may not be very rigorous. I tested a lot weeks ago, so I can't remember some details.

I didn't work on slots very much, but I think there should be an easy way to know if the slot is changed, whether we think it is an Object or something more complex.

I only put one static component in every drawer instead.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code you have now? That would make it easier to understand where you want to use the result from the slots

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Children should [`$emit` events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) to propagate changes. With that it wouldn't matter that the component is in a slot.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks for committing. What you said is correct, but in this scene, I don't know what is inside the drawer component, and the drawer component needs to respond when inner components change. I also checked some UI frameworks, seems like they always put a static component inside; I don't know if they are related.

Comment: @JasonLandbridge Hi! I added more info about what I have tested; I hope they are helpful.